# JQuery issue with IE8: Expected identifier

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I tried a few of the fixes I found here searching around but they don't seem to working so...

I am getting a Expected Identifier, string or number char 36 so the opening bracket.  I tried replaicing all the single quotes with double quotes no change...

```
if (($('#attachment_asset').length) && ($('p.please-wait').length == 0)) {
    $('.buttons').append($('<p/>', {
        class: 'please-wait', 
        text: 'Please wait, uploading your file...'
    }));
}
```

Seems to work fine everywhere but IE...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word `class` [seems to be reserved in IE](http://jonathonhill.net/2009-11-24/javascript-reserved-words-trigger-expected-identifier-error-on-ie/). Try to surround it with quotes:

```
$('.buttons').append($('<p/>', {
    "class": 'please-wait',
    text: 'Please wait, uploading your file...'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that.

The problem is happening with combination of something else in the file. Post the whole file. This works fine in ie9.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script language="javascript">
if (($('#attachment_asset').length) && ($('p.please-wait').length == 0)) {
    $('.buttons').append($('<p/>', {class: 'please-wait', text: 'Please wait, uploading your file...'}));
}
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.buttons').append($("<p>").addClass("please-wait").append("Please wait, uploading your file..."));
```